# Xubuntu 16.04 - saving files causes search

Tags: xubuntu

I'm using Xubuntu full time these days, and I'm noticing little things that I need help to change or understand.
One big thing is when I save a file in just about any app it seems to search for a filename rather than typing it in the filename text entry box.
For example, I open Mousepad, and save the file, then start typing the filename I want to save as. Instead of typing in the "Name" field, it seems to search in a text entry box in the lower right corner of the file browser.
Is there a way to change this behavior?

The other thing is that it doesn't automatically add a .txt extension. Geany doesn't do this either.

Can anyone help explain what's going on here and are there ways around this? It's a little annoying.

Comment: File name extensions are added by the applications (if they want to do it), not by the operating system. For example LibreOffice Writer adds .odt to the chosen file name.

I don't understand your first question concerning save and search. When I click on `save as` in most applications I have an entry field where I type the file name. No search done.

Comment: To add about the extensions — how can a text editor know which one do you want? Do you want .txt, or .log, or .conf, or .md, or .cpp, or .sh, or anything else? You could say "it can determine basing off the highlight/indentation mode", but there's plenty plain text formats — just look the first 3 I mentioned.

Comment: Forgot about this thread. Sorry. I found that when I go to save something, and change directories, then start typing the filename, the UI goes into a sort of search mode instead of typing into the text entry box. I always have to click very carefully in the filename text entry box to type the filename. Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: Here's what I mean. In the first part of the GIF, I just did a right mouse click and a "save as". I start typing and it overwrites the filename. Cool. I then do the same thing but choose a different directory. I then start typing and it shows a search box in the lower right instead of overwriting the filename like the first attempt. Why does it do this?
 https://imgur.com/6dNnhKP

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: anyone? Bueller?